# What's the difference between APR (Apache Portable Runtime) 1.3 and 0.9?

Tags: c++, apache, apr

I'm just getting started with APR and it seems that there are two supported versions developed side-by-side: http://apr.apache.org/

The docs don't explain the difference between 1.3.x and 0.9.x... Can anyone please shed light on the matter? Or in short, which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/Announcement0.9.html :

> This version of APR is principally a bug fix release, and is provided only for users requiring APR 0.9 compatibility. Most developers are encouraged to adopt the latest APR 1.x version to ensure the most comprehensive support and access to the latest features and enhancements.
>
> For example, the Apache HTTP Server Project's httpd 2.0 release uses APR 0.9 for binary compatibility, while later httpd 2.2 releases require APR 1.2 for better support and additional features.

Answer (score 1):

The [main page](http://apr.apache.org/) contains a link to [a list of all the changes](http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/CHANGES-APR-1.3) in each and every version.
Good luck.

Comment: Search for "Changes with APR 1.0" in the linked textfile.